# I want to host a chat application(Socketio, Node) in heroku. Need to spawn using throng

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

I am trying to use Socketio, throng to use WEB_CONCURRENCY environment variable and spawn as OOTB behavior of heroku.

How do we make sure the socket polling always goes to one worker node?
Do we need to use any sticky session module?

PS: I have enabled session affinity in heroku. So the polling is not going to all dynos.

But in the same dyno, for different workers, from the same client socket polling is not going to the same worker.

Anyone has a sample code or approach? I am not able to find any sample logic in internet.

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per my understanding you want to route clients based on their originating address, which you have multiple node clusters set up.

Yes you need to use sticky sessions - https://github.com/indutny/sticky-session

If you want to 'broadcast' then you would need an adapter (https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-adapter) to pass messages between clients.